# Sort the array in Ascending order using Javascript array=[40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10]; print both before and after sorting in this format

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```js
let array=[40,100,1,5,25,10];
array.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
console.log(array);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>

<p id="demo"></p>
 </html>
```

Example output: (array=[5,4,3,2,1] sorted array 1,2,3,4,5 in p tag)

Comment: Your sorting works so… what’s the issue you are facing?

Comment: @Terry May be he wants to append the result to the `demo` element

Comment: @terry I can't print both the original array and sorted array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the sorted array to a new variable(If you sort without assigning it to new variable, JS will consider it as changing the original array).

```
let array = [40,100,1,5,25,10];
let sortedArray = array.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
```

Now try to print both arrays as follows,

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Array = "+ array +" and sorted array = "+ sortedArray ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done this way!

```js
let array=[40,100,1,5,25,10];
let copy = [...array].sort(function(a,b){return a-b});

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "array="+array+" sorted array "+ copy ;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>

<p id="demo"></p>
 </html>
```

Comment: array=[5,4,3,2,1] sorted array 1,2,3,4,5

Answer (score 0):

Use   `array.slice()` method as it copies array  and returns a reference to a new array !

```
let array  = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
let sorted_array = array.slice();

sorted_array = sorted_array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a-b
});

console.log(array , sorted_array)
```

Comment: @Vishal M I think you can do the printing stuff by yourself easily

Answer (score -1):

```
let array = [40,100,1,5,25,10];
let arrSort = array.sort((a,b)=>{return a-b});
console.log(arrSort);

// (<0... a comes first 
//  =0... nothing will be changed 
//  >0... b comes first)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer